# Filter data, based on Latitude and Longitudes - Numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, latitude-longitude, slice

I have a dataset [here](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/nsidc0079_gsfc_bootstrap_seaice/final-gsfc/south/daily/2013/bt_20130221_f17_v02_s.bin) and it's specif [latitude](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/seaice/polar-stereo/tools/pss25lats_v3.dat) and [longitude](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/seaice/polar-stereo/tools/pss25lons_v3.dat)

```
import numpy as np

f = open('bt_20130221_f17_v02_s.bin', 'rb')
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint16).reshape(332, 316)
f.close()

raw_lat = open('pss25lats_v3.dat', 'rb')
lats = np.fromfile(raw_lat, dtype='<i4').reshape(332,316) / 100000.
raw_lat.close()

raw_lon = open('pss12lons_v3.dat', 'rb')
lons = np.fromfile(raw_lat, dtype='<i4').reshape(332,316) / 100000.
raw_lon.close()
```

The data values are presented here as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(data)
```

[image]

Based on those values, I desire to filter a regular portion of this data.
such as:

```
north = -59.7183
south = -65.3099
west = -65.743
east = -48.55

mask_lons = np.ma.masked_where(((lons > east) | (lons < west)), lons)
mask_lats = np.ma.masked_where(((lats < south) | (lats > north)), lats)

data_filtered = np.where(((lats == mask_lats) & (lons == mask_lons)),
                    data, 999)
```

this is the resultant image:
[image]

First question:
How can I slice this data_filtered to acquire only the valid values (i.e. only the matrix containing values != 999)?

Second question:
How do I do the same for lats and lons? How should I get only the non masked values as a sigle 2D array for each variable?
since mask_lons is:

```
In [176]: mask_lons
Out[176]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 ..., 
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- ..., -- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 ..., 
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: your post links to pss12lons instead of pss25lons, so the reshape isn't working

Comment: Sorry about this.
I'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need something like this:

```
inside = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(lons >= west,
                                       lons <= east),
                        np.logical_and(lats >= south,
                                       lats <= north))
```

Here is the full notebook:
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/ocefpaf/d609458086e2ad87eb62

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = (((south<=lats) & (lats<=north)) & ((west<=lons) & (lons<=east)))
data = np.ma.masked_where(data, ~mask)
```