# Numpy filter data based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Here's my question: I'm trying to filter an image based on the values of two coordinates. I can do this easily with a for loop:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 51)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = np.exp(X**2 + Y**2)

newZ = np.zeros(Z.shape)

for i, y_i in enumerate(y):
    for j, x_j in enumerate(x):
        if x_j > 0 and y_i > 0:
            newZ[i, j] = Z[i, j]
        else:
            newZ[i, j] = 0

plt.contourf(x, y, newZ)
plt.show()
```

but I'm pretty sure there should be a way to do it by indexing (as it should be faster) like:

```
Z = Z[y>0, x>0]
```

which doesn't work (`IndexError: Shape mismatch`)

I assume I could do this with a mask using masked array perhaps (it seems they are doing something like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156046/filter-data-based-on-latitude-and-longitudes-numpy)), but I wonder if there is a simple one-liner in normal numpy that I can't seem to figure out.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**, you have to use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
m = (y[:, None] > 0) | (x > 0)
newZ = np.where(m, Z, 0)

# OR
m = (y[:, None] > 0) | (x > 0)
newZ = np.zeros(Z.shape)
newZ[m] = Z[m]
```

Demo:

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 11)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 6)

Z = np.arange(len(y)*len(x)).reshape(len(y), len(x))

m = (y[:, None] > 0) | (x > 0)
newZ = np.zeros(Z.shape, dtype=int)
newZ[m] = Z[m]
```

Output:

```
>>> x
array([-1. , -0.8, -0.6, -0.4, -0.2,  0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ])

>>> y
array([-1. , -0.6, -0.2,  0.2,  0.6,  1. ])

>>> Z
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
       [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43],
       [44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]])

>>> newZ
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
       [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43],
       [44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]])
```

With [masked array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html):

```
>>> np.ma.masked_array(Z, ~m, fill_value=0)
masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, --, --, --, --, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43],
        [44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65]],
  mask=[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
         False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
         False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
         False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
         False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
         False, False],
        [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
         False, False]],
  fill_value=0)
```

---

IIUC, you are looking for [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
newZ = np.where(Z>0, Z, 0)
```

Same as:

```
m = Z>0
newZ = np.zeros(Z.shape)
newZ[m] = Z[m]
```

Alternative with [`np.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
newZ = np.clip(Z, 0, np.inf)
```

Comment: But this will filter based on Z, no? I want to filter based on x and y, in this case the top-right quadrant of the plot

Comment: Ah yes, of course, the broadcasting rules. I think this is the best answer to my question, r at least the one that required the least amount of reworking

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter based on more general boolean conditions over `x` and `y`, say `filter_x()` and `filter_y()`, you could use the meshgrid:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

newZ = np.zeros(Z.shape)
newZ[filter_x(X) & filter_y(Y)] = Z[filter_x(X) & filter_y(Y)]
```

`X` and `Y` give you all possible pairs of `x`s and `y`s.

Comment: this also seem to work, and as an added bonus it returns an array that has the same shape as the original array